# Given that a throw with 10 dice produced at least one ace, what is probability p of two or more aces

Tags: probability, self-learning

So, the question is:

Given that a throw with 10 dice produced at least one ace, what is probability p of two or more aces?

It is conditional probability problem.
The formula is $$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
P(A) - probability of getting two or more aces in a throw of 10 dice.

P(B) - probability that throw with 10 dice produced at least one ace.
$$P(B) = 1 - \frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}$$

But, i don't know what should i do further.
The correct answer is: $$1 - \frac{10*5^{9}}{(6^{10} - 5^{10})}$$

Comment: $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ and   $P(A \cap B) = P$(2 or more aces) = 1- $P$(No ace) - $P$(1 ace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A)$ is the probability that the throw produced at least $2$ aces, meaning that
$P(AB)$ is the probability that the throw produced at least one ace **and** at least two aces, which is the same as the probability that the throw produced at least two aces.

You therefore simply need to calculate $P(AB)$ which is the same as $P(A)$.

$P(A)$ is $1-x-y$ where $x$ is the probability that the throw produced **no** aces and $y$ is the probability that the throw produced *precisely one* ace.